# Tool to generate Class Diagrams from code (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, uml

Title says it all, really. I'm hoping there's some extension out there, or full blown software, that'll automatically generate class diagrams from my code. I looked over the Extension Gallery website but couldn't quite find something that meets my criteria.

I've inherited an application that looks like it was written by a CompSci 101 student-- no folder structure, lots of repeated code. Lots of mess spread out over 50 windows forms. There's absolutely no inheritance, no interfaces or anything. It's tremendously simple code, there's just a lot of it.

It'd be great to have something generate a diagram of the whole project so I can quickly see where there's redundant code so I can go back and refactor the hell out of this monstrosity. I really don't need any bells and whistles, just to see the class name, fields and methods. I would however like it to leave out any controls that were added on the form.

So, hypothetically, say I have `MyForm` which contains 2 `Textbox` one it and 1 `private int` in the code view, the class Diagram should look something like this:

```
| MyForm |
----------
| -int i |
----------
```

INSTEAD OF:

```
| MyForm |
----------
| -int i |
| -txt1  |
| -txt2  |
----------
```

Excuse the crude drawing :)

Comment: [Visual Studio 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=af2b5ncy014) does this out of the box.

Comment: @Ramhound Have to generate one per class manually, and it also shows all the controls on each and every form. I'm just looking for fields in the class' code behind and such.

Comment: Update your question with all requirements you have.  A class diagram should include the controls in a given class.  [UML Tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600802/tools-for-generating-uml-class-diagram-from-c-sharp-source-or-dll)

Answer (score 0):

To analyze code, I usually run doxygen on it first. It helps to generate an overview.
Don't forget to include the dot diagrams in the configuration file, which is needed to visualize caller and callee trees.